# Dynamic height of UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a problem with setting the height of an `UIWebView` dynamically. The webview loads a product description which contains html. I want the `UIWebView` to change its height based on the contents of the description.
I need to do it with `webViewDidFinishLoad` function. But I can not write function content.

Comment: Have you try `webView.sizeToFit()` inside `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `web view` height to `webview.scrollView.contentSize.height` in `webviewDidFinishLoad`

Comment: There is no such property `contentSize` in UIWebView class. It should be `webview.scrollView.contentSize.height`

Comment: Yes, this answer is old. At that time UIWebview was a subclass of UIScrollView. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView

{

    if ([webView isEqual:_viewWebDescription])
    {

       CGFloat height= webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;

       CGRect frameWebView=_viewWebDescription.frame;

       if (_viewWebDescription.frame.origin.y + height >= 745)
       {
           height= 745 - _viewWebDescription.frame.origin.y;
       }
       frameWebView.size.height=height;
       _viewWebDescription.frame= frameWebView;
    }

}
```